# Using Vue Data to Contain CSS Element

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am using Quasar framework alongside vue for the application development.

Here is my code:

```
<q-tooltip content-class="bg-amber text-black shadow-4" :offset="[10, 10]"> Save </q-tooltip>
<q-tooltip content-class="bg-amber text-black shadow-4" :offset="[10, 10]"> Open </q-tooltip>
<q-tooltip content-class="bg-amber text-black shadow-4" :offset="[10, 10]"> Exit </q-tooltip>
```

Basically, I am wondering if there is a way for me to save `bg-amber` in a parameter so that in case I want to change this class (color) in the future, I only have to change the value in the parameter rather than changing all of this.

Something like this:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      tooltipColor: 'bg-amber'
    }
  }
}
```

But if I do this, how should I be able to access this in the html side?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Maybe you can use :style="computedProperty" and work with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this way.

```
<q-tooltip :content-class="[tooltipColor, 'text-black' ,'shadow-4']" :offset="[10, 10]"> Save </q-tooltip>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you have to use inline style like this.

```html
<h1 :style="`background-color: ${myColor}`">Hello, Vue!</h1>
```

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      myColor: 'red'
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/imbyungjun/0xo4s7wb/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any attributes with the `v-bind` directive. (Using `:` before an attribute is a shorthand for the `v-bind`. When you do `v-bind`, you need to pass a JavaScript expression. (Just like you're doing in the `:offset` attribute)

```
<q-tooltip :content-class="contentClass" :offset="[10, 10]"> Exit </q-tooltip>
```

```
    computed: {
        contentClass() {
             return `${this.tooltipColor} text-black shadow-4`;
        }
    }
```